# How to fix application/x-httpd-php – Trouble in getting php to parse?

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

When I try to open URL, the website is downloaded and saying you have chosen to open :

**application/x-httpd-php**

Can anyone provide solution to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Probably belongs on Server Fault but it would help to see the relevant portion of your Apache config

Comment: How can I fix it?Is there any code or steps to fix it?Thanks

Comment: Do you have PHP installed?

Comment: Yes, PHP is installed.

Comment: Yes, it is downloading php code instead of displaying it.Do you have solution for it?

Comment: Did you actually read the link?

Comment: I am looking to link.Thanks